# How do I create a postgresql user and database from a fresh install?

Tags: ubuntu, database, administration, postgresql

I just installed postgresql onto an ubuntu box.

How can I create user foo with password bar and database baz, so that foo owns baz?
foo is not a unix user.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE ROLE foo WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'bar';
CREATE DATABASE baz OWNER foo;
```

Don't forget to modify `pg_hba.conf` to allow `foo` to connect with the `md5` method.